# Calculating Recall and precision for the Confusion matrix using torch7

Tags: lua, torch

I am using the tutorial [supervised](https://github.com/torch/tutorials/tree/master/2_supervised) and I would like to calculate the Recall and Precision. Is there way to calculate them in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved my data in desk then I used python